# make a filtre in mysql with case

Tags: mysql

i have a question i have 3 columns id, paydate, paydatefin

```
SELECT id, paydate, CASE 
WHEN paydatefin IS NULL 
THEN paydatefin = paydate
ELSE paydatefin
END AS  `paydatefin` 
FROM  `ws_crm_comenzi` 
WHERE  `sezonId` =  '4'
AND  `service_id` =  '1'
AND  `owner_id` =  '325'
AND  `finished` =  '1'
ORDER BY  `paydatefin` DESC



---------------------------------
|id | paydate    | paydatefin   |
|1  | 2016-08-29 | 2016-08-30   |
|2  | 2016-08-28 | 0000-00-00   |
|3  | 2016-08-28 | 2016-08-29   |
```

how ca i make a query if paydatefin is null then paydatefin = paydate

Comment: Try reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `paydatefin` is `NULL` then you need to supply `paydate` in place of that. 
But you were doing a comparison e.g. `(paydatefin = paydate)` would result in `0/1`.

Do this instead:

```
SELECT
    id,
    paydate,
    CASE
    WHEN paydatefin IS NULL THEN paydate
    ELSE    paydatefin END AS `paydatefinColumn`
FROM
    `ws_crm_comenzi`
WHERE
    `sezonId` = '4'
AND `service_id` = '1'
AND `owner_id` = '325'
AND `finished` = '1'
ORDER BY `paydatefinColumn` DESC
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT
        id,
        paydate,
        CASE
        WHEN paydatefin IS NULL OR paydatefin = '0000-00-00' THEN paydate
        ELSE    paydatefin END AS `paydatefinColumn`
    FROM
        `ws_crm_comenzi`
    WHERE
        `sezonId` = '4'
    AND `service_id` = '1'
    AND `owner_id` = '325'
    AND `finished` = '1'
    ORDER BY `paydatefinColumn` DESC
```

Comment: It gives same result  it not taking paydate as paydatefin

Comment: Would you please try now? And better share your current data set in `ws_crm_comenzi` table

Comment: i need that if paydatefin take the value of paydate

Comment: I got your problem. First try the updated query and then share your current data set from that table.

Comment: I see `paydatefin` is not NULL actually. It's having values like `0000-00-00`. Based on that I've updated the answer. Please check the query under **EDIT** section.

Answer (score 0):

Ca i do somthing like this ?

```
SELECT
        id,
        paydate,
        CASE
        WHEN paydatefin IS NULL OR paydatefin = '0000-00-00' THEN paydate
        ELSE    paydatefin END AS `paydatefinColumn`
    FROM
        `ws_crm_comenzi`
    WHERE
        `sezonId` = '4'
    AND `service_id` = '1'
    AND `owner_id` = '325'
    AND `finished` = '1'
    AND YEARWEEK(  `paydatefinColumn` ) = YEARWEEK( CURDATE( ) )
    ORDER BY `paydatefinColumn` DESC
```